# Android SDK makes my MacBook Pro shut down

Tags: android, macos

When I run an android studio on my Mac it opens perfectly. After Gradle built it shows "indexing..." message and my Mac freezes and shuts down. I tried installing IntelliJ and tried running it to create a project with android SDK, but I see the same problem the MacBook shuts down again after showing the same message at the bottom "indexing...".

Comment: for me it looks like a problem with your Mac

Comment: I would recommend you uninstall Android Studio completely delete all the folders of android studio and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hardware disk or memory issues. It could be hard drive issue.